# Java Initialize Variable Incremented

Tags: java, increment

Is it risky to initialize a global variable with an increment of another global variable?

**Example:**

```
int a=0; 
int b=a++; 
int c=a++; 
int d=a++;
```

**This should output:**

```
0,1,2,3
```

Could it happen that compiler could read a global value before the other?

Comment: how are you getting the output?

Comment: do you mean to say `a==0, b==1, c==2, d==3` ?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with doing this but a will end up being 3 not 0, since you are still incrementing it. Also b will start at 0 since you are effectively assigning _then_ incrementing. But I don't see why you would need to, if you're giving a variable _initial_ data you obviously know the initial data you want! ^^

Comment: Perhaps the developer will later want to change the original value.

Comment: But in that case it would still be just as easy to type out the new values (providing all he wanted to do was still increment)

Comment: Wrong question. You should ask: "should I use global variables"? And the answer to that is "No, you shouldn't". Meaning: worry about having a good design. I am wondering: what is the context of your question? Just curiosity; or what kind of problem do you want to solve?

Comment: var++ is **post increment** thus a is 0 , b is 0 (a becomes 1), c is 1 (a becomes 2) , d is 2 (a becomes 3)

Comment: should **global variable** be changed to **public static** ?? i doubt if the term global exists in java

Comment: @Jägermeister the question is basically: *may the compiler/jvm read/use the value of `b` before `a`?* And the answer is: no, the compiler won't allow it.

Answer (score 4):

It will behave as expected. If you try to use a field before it's defined, the compiler will throw an error:

```
public class Foo {
    int a = b++; //compiler error here
    int b = 0;
}
```

This is covered in [JLS 8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)

For your case, the *output* of the variables if they're not modified, would be:

```
a = 3
b = 0
c = 1
d = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Result will be `a=3, b=0, c=1, d=2`.

If all this variable declared in one class they will be initialized in order of occurrence in code.

PS: `b = 0` because `a++` get value and then increment variable.